# Under what circumstances can the members of the WTO bring about some changes to the WTO laws?

Tags: international-law, international, wto

Under what circumstances can the members of the WTO bring about some changes to the WTO laws? People have been calling for a reform of the WTO, but there doesn't seem to be a rule that says how the reform can be initiated and under what circumstances the rules can be changed or even how the rules would be changed. So is there any bit of information that is instructive on how the changes can take place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Trade_Organization) was established with a [treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrakesh_Agreement). To change a treaty, you need to sit its members (164 in this case, though arguably the ones representing major economies will flex more diplomatic muscle) around a table and get them to agree on the same thing and amend the treaty. The number of WTO members makes it particularly hard to change anything.

Comment: The EU shows it's possible to have a lawmaking framework inside a treaty, so this answer is technically too broad. It is accurate however for the WTO which misses such a framework.